# PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT Not Working

Tags: pdo, timeout, prepared-statement

I'm using MySQL and am getting the "MySQL server went away" error. I've tried setting `ATTR_TIMEOUT` in the PDO constructor as well as with the `setAttribute()` method, but neither are working. I've also set the MySQL connect_timeout variable.

No matter what time I specify PDO, within seconds, returns the timeout error.

I'm using a prepared statement for a very large insert. Is there a size restriction on PDO prepared statements that's breaking the connection? I've not been able to find any documentation referring to such a limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only length limitation is that of `max_allowed_packet` or `net_buffer_length` (most likely the former). I suggest raising `max_allowed_packet` if you have an INSERT of a very large row.

If you have an INSERT of many rows, you might be exceeding max_allowed_packet that way too. But it's easier to manage this by INSERTing a limited number of rows.

If you examine the output of mysqldump, for example, they don't try to insert the whole table in a single INSERT statement. They do use multi-row INSERT, but they do it in batches.

Comment: I upgraded MySQL, which allowed me to insert one of my large datasets, but your solution of running inserts in batches was a great idea which I've implemented with success. As my datasets grow, I expect the batch inserts to become even more of a necessity.